# How to like a post on other page with your page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

Well, i tried liking posts on my page with my page account, it works, but how can i like posts on other pages with my page?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
You simply do it the same way as with other accout, just changing page_id in request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply do it the same way as with other account, just changing page_id in request.